# Toggle background color of listview items on click

Tags: android, listview

I want the background color of Listview item to get change on the first click and restore the previous color to the second click (toggle). 
I am using the following code but on the second click its not working. and One more this app should remember the states of listview items evens after restarting it.

**DatabaseHelper.java**

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;    

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "listcolor.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "listtable";
    public static final String COL_1 = "title";
    public static final String COL_2 = "status";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + " (title TEXT, status TEXT )");
    }

    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean insertData(String title, String status) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL_1, title);
        contentValues.put(COL_2, status);
        db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
        return true;
    }

    public Cursor getData(String title) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select status from " + TABLE_NAME + " where title=" + title + "", null);
        return res;
    }
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String[] mobileArray = {"Android", "IPhone", "WindowsMobile", "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X"};
    DatabaseHelper myDb;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.listitem, mobileArray);

        final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                    long id) {

                String titletext = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();
                Cursor res = myDb.getData(titletext);
                if (res.getCount() > 0 && res.getString(0).equals("selected")) {
                    listView.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                    myDb.insertData(titletext, "De-selected");

                } else {
                    listView.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                    myDb.insertData(titletext, "selected");
                }


            }
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After a little loging, it turns out that after leaving the *listView.setOnItemClickListener* function, all the elements are reset to **unselected**. I Suggest you try to solve this problem by adding a [tag](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag(java.lang.Object)) to a selected item and then [check for it](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getTag()) in the if statement. The tags are set to *null* by default so you can use this to your advantage.

Working code snippet with Tags:

```
if (listView.getChildAt(position).getTag() != null) {
    listView.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    listView.getChildAt(position).setTag(null);
} else {
    listView.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
    listView.getChildAt(position).setTag("selected");
}
```

Comment: It worked but only till app remain open. Once it gets restarted all the changed color item gets restore.

Comment: Therefore you should store the state as others have already suggested. There are many different ways of doing so, please refer to the [data storage documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) to pick the most fitting one for your needs.

Comment: Made changes according to the documents but the app keeps restarting on button click. please give it a look. thanks..

Answer (score 0):

> but on the second click its not working

it's because whenever you tap on an item :

```
listView.getChildAt(position).isSelected()
```

returns **true**.

if you want to save the sate in order to keep the state after restarting the app. I would save the state in a database.(SQLite for example).

[Sugar](https://github.com/chennaione/sugar) can really help you. whenever the state changed you save it into the database and for changing the color you can decide based on the state you saved in DB.

Answer (score 0):

1. Set a tag "De-selected" to the textview in R.layout.listitem . This is the default tag to your view.

In the onClick, check the tag of the view clicked and change it based on the clicked state. You can toggle the colors based on the tag.

```
   <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:tag="De-selected"
  android:id="@+id/text"/>

if (listView.getChildAt(position).getTag().equals("selected")) {
                listView.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                listView.getChildAt(position).setTag("De-selected");
            } else {
                listView.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                listView.getChildAt(position).setTag("selected");
                listView.getChildAt(position).setSelected(true);
            }
```

2. To remember the states of listview items - when ever an item in the list is clicked , save the position . Similarly remove the saved postion when de-selected.
   In this way, you will have the list of all the positions of selected items in the list which you can save in your db and reload from db when app is relaunched , and set the tags of these selected postions to "selected" when loaded from db to show different colors for previously selected list items.

Comment: code worked but as you mentioned only till app remain open. Can you help in the db part as I am new to App development?

Comment: Please refer to this documentation along with the sample code in it.

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

Implement the database in you application. Will help you if you have any issues in implementation.

Comment: Made change but app keeps restarting please look into it

Comment: You have written code to add into db. Where are you retrieving data from db and setting colors based on retrieved values?

Comment: You will also need to change your array adapter to a custom adapter to set colors to view after getting values from db

Comment: in MainActivity file this line of codes are doing retrieving and comparing..

 String titletext = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();
                Cursor res = myDb.getData(titletext);
                if (res.getCount() > 0 && res.getString(0).equals("selected")) {
                    listView.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                    myDb.insertData(titletext, "De-selected");

                } else {...

Comment: All the code you have written is inside the onClickClistener.. Use a custom adapter , set the adapter and in the getView() of Adapter you can do the checking